# Pass custom objects to TestNG result listener

Tags: testng

I have a TestNG result listener that I reference from my Suite file

```
   <!-- Result Listener -->
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.test.automation.testng.ResultListener" methods="generateReport"/>
</listeners>
```

I use that result listener to write to a DB and store all my test results in mysql.  This works great except now I want to to add in some custom information such as timing data that I only have access to in my test. Not the timing of the actual test so I can't just use start and end time.

Is there a way to pass in a custom object to my result listener or the suite result object so I can then use that in my listener to write more info to the DB.

Comment: Are these custom information passed as arguments to your test method ?

Comment: As the test runsI gather statistics about the run.  Outside of anything TestNG knows.  I would like to pass those statistics back through the same result object because that is where my DB class gets all its info from.

Comment: To clarify they are not arguments but my test does things like create a file and drop that into a system.  I time and record in the test how long that feed takes.  I would like that into available when I am out in my result listener to include in my test results.  All TestNG knows about is pass or fail from the asserts

Comment: Not really. Testng has a Reporter class. It has a log method where you can write the logs for a particular test and then in the listener you can use the getOutput method and pass iTestResult context which will be available in  the listener to get the relevant logs. From there you can parse out what you want . I think that should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

`Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setAttribute(name,value)`

in your tests and then use the result object to get the attribute.

Comment: This is a better option .

Comment: i am getting value as null when i use Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getAttribute("name")

Answer (score 0):

something like this can be used as a hack -

```
Reporter.log("Time:"+time); // in the test
```

then in the listener

```
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult arg0) {
          Reporter.getOutput(arg0); // this will fetch that log and you can parse it and make it meaningful

}
```

Of course this will fetch all the logs as a List and you have to work on it.

Comment: This was helpful I did not realize I could use a "ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();"   in something like an @AfterClass to get the current test context.  I can then use that to create and populate a custom class with test info and my custom info.